# What is the pythonic way to remove trailing spaces from a string?

Tags: python

The parameter to the function satisfy these rules:

1. It does not have any leading whitespace
2. It might have trailing whitespaces
3. There might be interleaved whitespaces in the string.

Goal: remove duplicate whitespaces that are interleaved & strip trailing whitespaces.

This is how I am doing it now:

```
# toks - a priori no leading space
def squeeze(toks):
  import re
  p = re.compile(r'\W+')
  a = p.split( toks ) 
  for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if len(a[i]) == 0:
      del a[i]
  return ' '.join(a) 

>>> toks( '  Mary  Decker   is hot   ' )
Mary Decker is hot
```

Can this be improved ? Pythonic enough ?

Comment: I must be not awake enough yet: anything wrong with `' '.join(test.split())`? (Where test is your string.)

Comment: Your parameter violates your rule #1: It has leading whitespace.

Comment: Ulrich: the ' '.join() will re-introduce spaces among the empty elements from the .split(); also .split() is different than .split(' ').  You have to at least use a list comprehension to filter out the empty results from the split().

Comment: @Jim Dennis: Without any parameters, `split()` will split on whitespace, discarding leading and trailing whitespace so there will be no empty elements.

Comment: @Jim Dennis: The list produced by `s.split()` (which is what Ulrich used) NEVER contains an empty element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
" ".join(toks.split())
```

PS. Is there a subliminal message in this question? ;-)

Comment: `.split()` is not the same as `.split(' ')` and he might want to preserve tabs, new lines and, conceivably, other whitespace.

Comment: Right, but the question didn't imply that he wanted to preserve those. See the example.

Comment: In fact the question said "remove duplicate whitespaces that are interleaved" of which Keith's answer is the most sensible interpretation.

Comment: No subliminal messages. Just a python noob trying not to shoot himself in the foot. That solution is so elegant.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use rstrip()?

```
some_string.rstrip()
```

or strip() for stripping the string from both sides?

In addition: the strip() methods also support to pass in arbitrary strip characters:

```
string.strip = strip(s, chars=None)
    strip(s [,chars]) -> string
```

Related: if you need to strip whitespaces in-between: split the string, strip the terms and re-join it.

Reading the API helps!

Comment: That won't remove multiple spaces from the middle.

Comment: The question is about trailing spaces from a string - not about trailing spaces inside the words of a string.

Comment: example does however, might need to rephrase question

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions literally:

Yes, it could be improved. The first improvement would be to make it work.

```
>>> squeeze('x    !    y')
'x y' # oops
```

Problem 1: You are using \W+ (non-word characters) when you should be using \s+ (whitespace characters)

```
>>> toks = 'x  !  y  z  '
>>> re.split('\W+', toks)
['x', 'y', 'z', '']
>>> re.split('\s+', toks)
['x', '!', 'y', 'z', '']
```

Problem 2: The loop to delete empty strings works, *but only by accident.* If you wanted a general-purpose loop to delete empty strings in situ, you would need to work backwards, otherwise your subscript i would get out of whack with the number of elements remaining. It works here because re.split() without a capturing group can produce empty elements only at the start and end. You have defined away the start problem, and the end case doesn't cause a problem because there have been no prior deletions. So you are left with a very ugly loop which could be replaced by two lines:

```
if a and not a[-1]: # guard against empty list
    del a[-1]
```

However unless your string is very long and you are worried about speed (in which case you probably shouldn't be using re), you'd probably want to allow for leading whitespace (assertions like "my data doesn't have leading whitespace" are ignored by convention) and just do it in a loop on the fly:

`a = [x for x in p.split(toks) if x]`

Next step is to avoid building the list `a`:

```
return ' '.join(x for x in p.split(toks) if x)
```

Now you did mention "Pythonic" ... so let's throw out all that re import and compile overhead stuff, and the genxp and just do this:

```
return ' '.join(toks.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tend not to use the `re` module if I can do the job reasonably with
the built-in functions and features.  For example:

```
def toks(s):
    return ' '.join([x for x in s.split(' ') if x])
```

... seems to accomplish the same goal with only built in `split`, `join`, and the list comprehension to filter our empty elements of the split string.

Is that more "Pythonic?" I think so.  However my opinion is hardly authoritative.

This could be done as a lambda expression as well; and I think that would not be Pythonic.

Incidentally  this assumes that you want to ONLY squeeze out duplicate spaces and trim leading and trailing spaces.  If your intent is to munge all whitespace sequences into single spaces (and trim leading and trailing) then change `s.split(' ')` to `s.split()` -- passing no argument, or `None`, to the `split()` method is different than passing it a space.

Comment: Yes, and the subject line said "trailing spaces."  I've explained how to implement either set of semantics.

Comment: Subject lines are notoriously inaccurate. In this case his detailed spec AND his code make it quite plain that he wants to normalise internal whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code more Pythonic, you must realize that in Python, **a[i]** being a string, instead of `deleting a[i] if a[i]==''` , it is better `keeping a[i] if a[i]!=''` .

So, instead of

```
def squeeze(toks):
    import re
    p = re.compile(r'\W+')
    a = p.split( toks )
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if len(a[i]) == 0:
            del a[i]
    return ' '.join(a)
```

write

```
def squeeze(toks):
    import re
    p = re.compile(r'\W+')
    a = p.split( toks )
    a = [x for x in a if x]
    return ' '.join(a)
```

and then

```
def squeeze(toks):
    import re
    p = re.compile(r'\W+')
    return ' '.join([x for x in p.split( toks ) if x])
```

Then, taking account that a function can receive a generator as well as a list:

```
def squeeze(toks):
    import re
    p = re.compile(r'\W+')
    return ' '.join((x for x in p.split( toks ) if x))
```

and that doubling parentheses isn't obligatory:

```
def squeeze(toks):
    import re
    p = re.compile(r'\W+')
    return ' '.join(x for x in p.split( toks ) if x)
```

.

.

Additionally, instead of obliging Python to verify if `re` is or isn't present in the namespace of the function **squeeze()** each time it is called (it is what it does), it would be better to pass `re` as an argument by defautlt :

```
import re
def squeeze(toks,re = re):
    p = re.compile(r'\W+')
    return ' '.join(x for x in p.split( toks ) if x)
```

and , even better:

```
import re
def squeeze(toks,p = re.compile(r'\W+')):
    return ' '.join(x for x in p.split( toks ) if x)
```

.

.

Remark: the `if x` part  in the expression is useful only to leave apart the heading `''` and the ending `''` occuring in the list `p.split( toks )` when toks begins and  ends with  whitespaces.

But , instead of splitting, it is as much good to keep what is desired:

```
import re
def squeeze(toks,p = re.compile(r'\w+')):
    return ' '.join(p.findall(toks))
```

.

.

All that said, the pattern  `r'\W+'` in your question  is wrong for your purpose, as  John Machin pointed it out.

If you want to compress internal whitespaces and to remove trailing whitespaces, whitespace being taken in its pure sense designating the set of characters  `' ' , '\f' , '\n' , '\r' , '\t' , '\v'` ( see  \s in [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)) , you must replace your spliting with this one:

```
import re
def squeeze(toks,p = re.compile(r'\s+')):
    return ' '.join(x for x in  p.split( toks ) if x)
```

or, keeping the right substrings:

```
import re
def squeeze(toks,p = re.compile(r'\S+')):
    return ' '.join(p.findall(toks))
```

which is nothing else than the simpler and faster expression `' '.join(toks.split())`

But if you want in fact just to compress internal and remove trailing characters `' '` and `'\t'` , keeping the newlines untouched, you will use

```
import re
def squeeze(toks,p = re.compile(r'[^ \t]+')):
    return ' '.join(p.findall(toks))
```

and that can't be replaced by anything else.

Comment: Your set of (ASCII) whitespace characters doesn't include space!?

Comment: @John Machin I apologize, I did an omission. Sure, a blank is a whitespace. I took the list in the description of ``\s`` in (http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re)

Comment: @eyquem: No you didn't -- read it again carefully: `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`

Comment: @John Machin What do you mean ? Do you want me to write : _whitespace being taken in its pure sense designating **each character** in the set of characters ``' ' , '\f' , '\n' , '\r' , '\t' , '\v'``_ ?

Comment: @eyquem: No. I presumed that "I took the list" happened originally. However you probably meant that it happened at fixup time. Sorry.

Comment: @John Machin I don't understand the importance of 'originally' or 'at fixup time'. I referred to freedictionary.com to know the meaning of 'fixup' but I'm not more advanced. You know english isn't my natural language, so I frequently have difficulty to understand the subtelties of english sentences, and I'm sorry to express myself in an awkward literary style.

Comment: @John Machin When I wrote _'I took the list in the description of \s in the docs'_, it means that when I wanted to know what are precisely the characters covered by this appelation, 'whitespace', I found them in the Python doc on module re. I could have written "I refer to the definition of whitespace I found in the doc". It doesn't mean that I did a copy-and-paste. In fact, I wrote the list, or set, of the concerned characters, from memory [mine, not RAM :)) ] , in a different order than in the doc because I remind them with a mnemonic....

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old. But why not use regex?

```
import re

result = '  Mary  Decker   is hot   '
print(f"=={result}==")

result = re.sub('\s+$', '', result)
print(f"=={result}==")

result = re.sub('^\s+', '', result)
print(f"=={result}==")

result = re.sub('\s+', ' ', result)
print(f"=={result}==")
```

The output is

```
==  Mary  Decker   is hot   ==
==  Mary  Decker   is hot==
==Mary  Decker   is hot==
==Mary Decker is hot==
```